# Firebase - multiple filtering by up-votes and entries marked as "read"

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, filtering

I know this question has been asked loads of times and I'm aware of the different workarounds but I can't figure out a nice way to apply those workarounds to my problem.

I'm building an app integrating with Firebase that has the concept of stories. I want the app to retrieve stories ordered by up-votes (no big deal so far).

```
stories
  <some-story-id-1>
    id: "<some-story-id-1>"
    published: true
    title: "Test"
    userId: "<some-user-id>"
    points: 12
```

**But** I also want to flag when individual users have read a story so they don't get that story displayed to them again.

So typically I would want to enrich my user data similar to the below.

```
users
  <some-user-id>
    stories-read
      <some-story-id-1>: true
      <some-story-id-2>: true
```

So I need to retrieve paginated results for stories, ordered by up-vote, that *excludes* stories that are already flagged as *read* by a user.

Now I could just retrieve the data ordered *only* by up-vote and then omit the stories marked as *read* on the client side but this is an awful waste of data (and considering this is how Google charge people, it could end up costing a lot of money).

Is there a better way to achieve the same behaviour without wasting data?

Answer (score 2):

This is a really good thought & design question

There are number of solutions but here's one where you keep track of which messages have been *read* by users.

Given a structure

```
messages
  msg_0
    msg: "Some message
    read_by:
      user_0: true
      user_1: true
  msg_1
    msg: "Another message"
    read_by:
      user_2: true
  msg_2
    msg: "Yipee"
    read_by
      user_1: true
```

let's assume we want to get all messages that user_0 has NOT read, which would be 1 and 2 in this example.

I don't know your platform, but here's how we'd do it in Swift.

```
let ref = self.ref.child("messages")
let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "read_by/user_0").queryEqual(toValue: nil)
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        print(snap)
    }
})
```

This returns

```
Snap (msg_1) {
    msg = "Another message";
    "read_by" =     {
        "user_2" = 1;
    };
}
Snap (msg_2) {
    msg = "Yipee";
    "read_by" =     {
        "user_1" = 1;
    };
}
```

So what we are doing is query'ing Firebase for all child read_by nodes for the absence of user_0 (nil), which are the ones user has not read.

When user_0 reads it, just add user_0: true to the read_by node of the message.

**Edit:**

The above is only a partial solution and omits ordering by vote. Let me try again and provide a complete solution. Given the structure

```
users
  uid_0
    name: "Biff"
    unread_messages
       msg_0001:
           votes: -10
       msg_0005:
           votes: -20
       msg_0022:
            votes: -5
  uid_1
    name: "Henry"
    unread_messages
       msg_0003:
           votes: -4
       msg_0009:
           votes: -2
```

then to read in messages that uid_0 has not read we do the following

```
var messageKeys = [String]()

func getUnreadMessages() {

    let ref = self.ref.child("users").child("uid_0/unread_messages")
    let query = ref.queryOrdered(byChild: "votes")
    query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            self.messageKeys.append(key)
        }
    })
}
```

The above code gets a reference to the unread messages (the key) ordered by # of votes. Note that the number of votes is stored as a negative value, which will read them in descending order. As an alternative, keep them as a positive value and store both the key and number of votes in the array (as an array of classes for example) and sort the array in code.

Then get the messages:

```
for msgKey in messageKeys {
   let ref = self.ref.child("messages").child(msgKey)
   ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
       let msgDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
       let msg = msgDict["msg"] as! String
       print(msg)
   })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Jay! This makes sense, but the issue I was getting at was the restriction that Firebase has that you can only filter/order by *one* key. I need to filter by un-read **and** order by paginated up-votes, descending. Also, as far as I'm aware, if I retrieve a node in firebase then I have to retrieve all its children - i.e. if I retrieve messages/msg_0 then every single user that reads that message will download the values under the property "read_by". In my case all stories are public so this leads to a lot of extra data being downloaded

Comment: @JamesR My apologies for lack of reading skills :-) I have updated my answer with a complete solution.

Comment: Hi Jay, thanks for coming back, really appreciate your input. I think this will technically solve the issue but I still have concerns with the size of the data. Perhaps this works better in a world of messages that are restricted to certain users. Unfortunately the schema I am building has the concept of "stories" which exist as public posts, so *every* user can see every story in the database. If someone creates a new story then I would need to create a cloud function to create an entry for every user in the system. If I have thousands of stories and millions of users then this is a lot

Comment: Unless I'm missing something else here?

Comment: @JamesR If you have millions of users, then a huge congrats! lol. ;-) If you want to keep track of who's read what, that data needs to be stored somewhere. Either with the story or with the user or maybe in another node that ties users and stories together. Storing it in the users node per my solution is a tiny bit for data for the user. If a new story get's posted it would need to be added to every users node and while that could be a large number of users, it's also a small amount of data per user.

Comment: Haha well I don't, but I aspire to :) The other consideration is that when someone up/downvotes a story then I need a cloud function to change every user's "votes" entry to reflect the source of truth. Firebase comes so close to relieving the pain of building out a back-end but really falls short with filtering. Everything feels like a workaround. I think I'm going to resort more to a feed-like UI that will remove my need to flag entries as "read". This is a really important discussion though so would love others to chime in with their opinions on Firebase. Thank you for your help!